# Where is the commenting tool?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot find any clickable under the posts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9086/where-is-the-commenting-tool?/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-02-16**:
There should be a button saying "Post a comment" right below any reply

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-02-16**:
I am allowed to comment only with my own post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to have at least 10 karma in order to be able to add comments. EDIT: To other posts.  You can always comment on your own posts.

Answer some questions (or just asking this one might be enough), and then you will receive that capability.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well that seems like a little odd requirement. Could lead to some posts that are mainly intended to acquire the needed Karma points for commenting. Feel a bit guilty with this post myself :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

+1: These karma points don't allow for new users to step into discussions easily.

---

Originally posted by [tschamm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2481/tschamm/) with karma: 41 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

+1 on the Karma points required to comment being obnoxious - the questions I feel qualified to help with often require clarification, which doesn't belong in an actual answer ... so I just pass on them.

(and yes, I would have put this as a comment under @tscharmm's answer, if only I was able to.)

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-30**:
@lindzey @tschamm I know this is a problem, but spam is also a problem.  And the threshold is pretty important for protecting posts from being spammed in the comments.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-30**:
Ticketed: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3975